# magento products been shuffling on homepage?

Tags: magento-1.9

i am in the process of implementing the product list , but the thing is , do not know why its been shuffling . if somebody have experience on how to get rid of this.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="2" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

the above code is in my homepage .

Comment: check product collection sort order something like 
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356019/magento-get-products-from-category-order-by-rand) ?

Comment: echo  $productcollection->getSelect() in your phtml file

Comment: ok order of collection is based on position in that category. it should not shuffle than

Comment: but its been shuffling , any idea why its happening ?

Comment: have you changed anything in phtml file or is just core file ?

Comment: yes i just incorporate design in this file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to stop shuffling go to admin panel. click on catalog> manage categories > select your category  > display settings > Available Product Listing Sort By > select your desired seting either price , name or valuee , now your products would not be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to control the number of columns in product listing, please use the following code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="2" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Refresh cache and check it.

Thanks.

Comment: just up vote this ques, so that others can get benefit from this

Answer (score 1):

check the product block,for ->order('rand()')

```
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
        $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
        $collection->addStoreFilter();
        $this->setProductCollection($collection);
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
```